# Fresco not loading remote url data, when Request level is set to DISK_CACHE

Tags: android, fresco

I am trying to use fresco for calling and then "disk caching" network image in my app but fresco is not loading the image at all.

Here is the code that i am using, the motif behind using image request and DraweeController is to store the data into disk_cache as soon as it is loaded.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(details.getImgUrl());
        ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder
                .newBuilderWithSource(uri)
                .setLowestPermittedRequestLevel(ImageRequest.RequestLevel.DISK_CACHE)
                .build();

            AbstractDraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setImageRequest(request)
                    .setOldController(banner.getController())
                    .build();
            banner.setController(controller);
```

Although if i use `ImageRequest.RequestLevel.FULL_FETCH` the images are loaded but are not cached

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

Check Plamenkos answer on this link.. https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/80

if you ask pipeline for an encoded image, and specify DISK_CACHE with ImageRequestBuilder.setLowestPermittedRequestLevel, the pipeline will return you the JPEG bytes if the image is found anywhere up to disk cache, or null if the image is not found and a full-fetch would have to be performed.

**instead of fresco**

Try to use **GlideApp** for image caching. It will solve your issue. Well you can integrate it easily, if you stuck somewhere then I will help you on that. But make sure you use **GlideApp** not just **Glide**.

I hope I did not mis-understand your question and provide a wrong answer.